# PHP - Anonymous Function as Static Array Element

Tags: php, class, function, static, anonymous-function

I'm attempting to make an achievement system for a memorization website ("You memorized 50 cards," etc.), and the method I'm trying to use is an array of anonymous functions:

```
class AchievementController extends Controller
{
    private static $rules = array(
        'card'=>array(
            1=>function() {
                //do check for achievement
            },
            2=>function() {
                //do check for achievement
            }
         ),
         'set'=>array(
            5=>function() {
                //do check for achievement
            },
            6=>function() {
                //do check for achievement
            },
         )
    );
    //...
}
```

The idea is that certain types of rules for achievements will be checked at certain times, i.e. when you learn a new card, the `card` subset will be checked. I had hoped to use a `foreach` loop like this:

```
foreach(self::$rules[$type] as $rule)
{
    $rule();
}
```

However, when I try to declare the `$rules` array, I get this error:

`PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'function' (T_FUNCTION) in`
`/.../controllers/achievement.php on line 24`

If I declare `$rules` inside a function (NOT static), it works just fine. I can't put it inside a constructor, because this class is being used statically, so no constructor will be called.

My question is, is it possible for me to do this in a static array? Or ought I just to do something else?

(Extra question: Is there a better way than this to do achievements?)

Comment: What version of php are you running... anonymous functions aren't available until 5.3.

Comment: Why so many closures? Seems unlikely all the logic is mutually exclusive? As such, consider subclassing and using polymorphism.

Comment: @Orangepill, I'm using version 5.3.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary, these achievements are all unique, (learned 10 cards, learned 50 cards), so I was planning to have other functions be reused inside these anonymous ones.

Comment: @Alex - I wasn't being sarcastic, I was being serious... while I don't believe that statics are an antipattern, I do believe that they can cause a lot of problems that can be eliminated by a simple instantiation

Comment: @AlexMorrise Jari's answer is the solution.

Comment: @Alex Morrise, you asked *Is there a better way than this to do achievements?* I told you one.

Comment: @MarkBaker, I'm sorry, I honestly thought you were being funny. I understand what you mean. I think I will go with instantiation per Jari's answer.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary, this whole framework is based on polymorphism so because of your suggestion I will probably put some of this logic in subclasses. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No way you can pre-declare them (anonymous functions) in a class. You can do it inside a class method though:

```
class AchievementController extends Controller {
  public static $rules = array() ;

  public static function setup(){
    self::$rules = array(
      0 => function(){
        echo "One-statement array" ;
      }) ;

    //OR


    self::$rules[0] = function(){
      //Echo "ASD" ;
    } ;
    self::$rules[1] = function(){
      //Echo "ASD2" ;
    }
  }
}

AchievementController::setup() ; //Just calling pseudo-constructor for static class
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do in a static array like this.  The property declaration must be constant as noted in PHP docs here (http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php).

> This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.

What you could perhaps do is have the function names defined statically, i.e.:

```
private static $rules = array(
    'card'=>array('function1', 'function2'),
    'set'=>array('function3', 'function4')
);
```

And then you could simply use these references to call NAMED method calls:

```
public static function function1 () {
     // some logic
}

public static function function2 () {
    // some logic
}
```

However, this whole thing seems very clunky. Seems to me you might want to have an achievement interface which defines certain methods (i.e. `checkAchievements`) and then have concrete implementing classes for cards, sets, etc.

Comment: @bwoebi The closure cannot be evaluated at compile time. It is not a constant value. If the closure did indeed do something trivial like `function() { return true; }` which is constant-like than there would be no need for the closure at all.

Comment: uh, let's call it static dependency injection. with prefilled variables in class

Comment: And I'd bet the closure could be evaluated at compile time - just no `use()`?

Answer (score 1):

Current PHP grammar only supports primitive types, arrays and compile time constants in predefined class variables. For an exact list of what it supports see also http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_TRUNK/Zend/zend_language_parser.y#945.

What you can do is maybe declaring your class' methods as private and the use __callStatic as a wrapper. If the static property is then not yet set, set them. And then call the class method.

Or just make some setup at the beginning. like @Jari suggested.